# error message when trying to install jquery with node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am trying to use jQuery in a node.js application. It seems easy enough according to [Can I use jQuery with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js) but when I tried to run `npm install jQuery jsdom htmlparser xmlhttprequest` and simply `npm install jQuery` neither one seemed to work for me. Here is the full text of the error message I got:

```
    $ npm install jQuery jsdom htmlparser xmlhttprequest
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jQuery
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jsdom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jsdom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jQuery
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings

> contextify@0.1.2 install /Users/nicmeiring/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify
> node-gyp rebuild

info it worked if it ends with ok 
spawn python [ '/Users/nicmeiring/.node-gyp/0.6.14/tools/gyp_addon',
  'binding.gyp',
  '-I/Users/nicmeiring/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/build/config.gypi',
  '-f',
  'make' ]
ERR! Error: not found: make
    at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:43:28)
    at E (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:46:29)
    at Object.oncomplete (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:57:16)
ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dependency failed, continuing contextify@0.1.2
xmlhttprequest@1.3.0 ./node_modules/xmlhttprequest 
jquery@1.6.3 ./node_modules/jquery 
htmlparser@1.7.5 ./node_modules/htmlparser 
jsdom@0.2.13 ./node_modules/jsdom 
├── request@2.9.200
└── cssom@0.2.3
```

In my node.js application file (app.js) I include the jquery module using `var $ = require('jQuery)`, but, as expected, it returns an error when I try to use jQuery in my application. Any ideas what is causing the install to fail? Thanks

UPDATE:
the jquery module successfully installed but when I try to run my app I am getting a new error. Here are the scripts:

app.js

```
   var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , $ = require('jquery');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(require('stylus').middleware({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/', routes.getData);

app.listen(4000);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
```

and index.js

```
var $ = require('jquery');

exports.index = function(req, res){
  console.log("rendering index.html")
  res.render('layout', { title: 'Express' })
};


var link = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&callback=?"

exports.getData = $.ajax({
                      url: link,
                      dataType: JSON,
                      data: data,
                      success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log(data.parse.text['*']);
                      }
});
```

and here is the error I am getting when I start up the app

```
    Nic-Meirings-MacBook-Pro:Wiki2 nicmeiring$ node app

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nicmeiring/Sites/Wiki2/routes/index.js:16:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nicmeiring/Sites/Wiki2/app.js:7:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
```

Comment: When you type "make" to console, what do you see? This works well on my Ubuntu with Node 0.6.14

Comment: where should i be typing "make"

Comment: to the place you are typing npm install ... ?

Comment: Nic-Meirings-MacBook-Pro:~ nicmeiring$ make
-bash: make: command not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are missing "make" which comes with Developer Tools. Here is the related SO question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1470005/337504

Comment: thanks. ill check that out. what exactly should i be downloading from developer.apple.com?

Comment: ok thanks ill look. would you mind checking out my updated code above?