# Error Installing Jekyll - Native Extension Build

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, installation, jekyll

I'm having some trouble installing jekyll. Can't quite figure out how to patch the missing link. I think it's an update to Ruby, but RVM is having trouble installing alternate versions of ruby as well.

Heres the full post:

```
$ sudo gem install jekyll    

ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.1/ext/gem_make.out
```

Does this mean I need to update the version of ruby I'm using via rvm?

Comment: What commands specifically are you running to update RVM and then switch your ruby version?

Comment: Hey Noah, I was trying $ rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p320

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave the exact commands you issued followed by the complete output. Try to use code highlighting too.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Noah, I added the command I issued for the jekyll install and what it output.

Comment: what does `which make` return?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that either you system doesn't know where make is located at or you don't have it installed. The easiest way to fix this (and probably other issues you'll run into trying to get a ruby system up and running) is to install xcode.

You can get it at http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12 for lion. Or it came on a CD with your computer for earlier versions.

If you're using Lion, please see comments below for a link to how to install developer tools on Lion.

Comment: Great! Thanks Noah, glad to hear that's the problem. About 30 min into the install now.

Comment: I saw you're relatively new here so *if* my solution works you should come back and mark it as an acceptable answer so others can benefit from it.

Comment: Absolutely, Thanks so much for your help @NoahClark - Unfortunately though, I've installed xcode and am still getting the same issue when running the `sudo gem install jekyll` - I'll try and update ruby again via rvm?

Comment: running the `which make` command also is still coming back empty

Comment: What does typing in /usr/bin/make at the command line give you? Have you ever compiled anything for source on your system before?

Comment: I'm getting `/usr/bin/make: No such file or directory`. But I've actually just noticed something rather peculiar, My .gem .rvm .gitconfig files are are installed in the /Users/Username directory. This is actually a work computer I've not used much for dev, I am definitely fairly new to command line tools and had all of this working on my personal mac, using the work computer now I'm thinking the user settings are all jammed up. I don't think some important things are installed in the right directories.

Comment: Which means I don't think my system knows where make is located. With xcode installed it has to be there.

Comment: .gem, .rvm and .gitconfig could (and probably should) be in your home directory. That's not weird. Can you confirm that xcode is installed by running it? Are you on Lion? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469994/using-make-on-osx

Comment: Yeah, that's what I referencing from the link above! Glad you found it!

Answer (score 195):

## Ubuntu

1. `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`
2. `gem install jekyll`

Comment: but it does solve my problem in Ubuntu, since the question title doesn't mention the os

Comment: OP did not mention it explicitly but the error message with the `/System/Library/Frameworks` was pretty revealing. Worked for me none the less on Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: This solution works on Raspberry Pi, just need add sudo for the second command: sudo gem install jekyll

Comment: Thank you! I had to `sudo apt-get remove ruby` as I had Ruby 1.9.3, and it wouldn't let me `sudo gem install jekyll`.

Comment: but no one says anything about Windows :(

Comment: Installing ruby dev fixed the issue. PS: For fedora: ```# dnf install ruby ruby-dev```

Comment: Same in my case, version supplied didn't match, but tried ruby-dev then worked, as usual when you miss some packages that requires compiling.

Comment: I needed `sudo` on both commands. Other than that: GREAT. (Unbuntu MATE 14.04)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error on Ubuntu and [this](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/209) helped me sort it out.

You must have ruby-dev installed

```
apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Answer (score 6):

If you installed XCode and command line tools are **still** missing go to Terminal and

`xcode-select --install`

it will prompt you to install these tools. After that just follow [SrBlanco´s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23298734/4008608) answer. That solved the problem for me.

Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

Need to install "make".
I am using Ubuntu 12.10.
`sudo apt-get install make`
Should work on any Debian based distro.

Answer (score 3):

Note: this problem also occurs on newer MacBook Pro models that come with Mavericks pre-installed. I updated another post with my own solution that didn't involve Xcode at all. My system had the Xcode developer tools installed when I got the machine.

[ERROR: Error installing jekyll: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460117/error-error-installing-jekyll-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension/23298607#23298607)

Answer (score 2):

Install Xcode as mentioned if you don't have it installed already (https://developer.apple.com/xcode/). **Plus** you need the command line tools.

Open Xcode. Go to `Preferences > Downloads > Install Command Line Tools`

Comment: Please don't post the same answer multiple times. Especially if you're essentially repeating what the other answers say. If you find duplicate questions, flag the so they can be merged.

Comment: I answered two questions with the same answer. Because I guess people will land on both answers. I don't know what you mean by repeating the other answers! The part with the command line tools is nowhere mentioned but an essential part of the solution. Xcode alone gets you nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

Installing command line tools for Xcode solved the problem for me on my Mac

`xcode-select --install`.

Answer (score 2):

- sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
- sudo gem install jekyll

hope this will help, it works with me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same exact error when trying to install Jekyll, and the following steps from this link helped me. Just in case anyone else comes across this!

http://davidensinger.com/2013/03/installing-jekyll/

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue in my Fedora 22 setup. I had `ruby` installed but didn't have `ruby-devel`. Installing `ruby-devel` fixed the issue for me.

```
dnf install -y ruby-devel
```

For older systems:

```
yum install -y ruby-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

## I followed this on Ubuntu/Linux Mint

1. `sudo apt install build-essential`
2. `sudo apt install ruby-dev`
3. `sudo gem install jekyll`

Answer (score 0):

An addendum: You can install **XCode now from the App Store** on Mountain Lion. The process is transparent and pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with you.

I use Mac OS X 10.9 develop preview version, and I had installed gcc and Xcode.

But my Xcode version is 4.6.

Then I install the Xcode 5.0

After that I type `sudo gem install jekyll` in the terminal again. Then it works.

Wish it could help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Xcode and going to perferencs > downloads > install commandline tools WORKS!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on Debian, I had forgot to run this command:

```
~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Answer (score 0):

All these answers did NOT work for me.

If you're looking for a solution on ubuntu 14.04, do this:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev zlib1g-dev nodejs
sudo gem install jekyll -v 2.5.3
```

Unfortunately, nodejs is required because of a bug in Jekyll that enforces existence of runtime JS engine even though it doesn't need one.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu, this helped in my case:

```
apt-get install libffi-dev
```

A general advice is to just follow what is displayed as the reason for the error and hopefully you'll be provided with a log file in which the first line suggests which package should be installed, in my case:

```
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.21/mkmf.log
```

Answer (score 0):

## MacOS

my solution to this problem

1. install xcode
2. type `xcode-select --install` in the command line
3. type `sudo gem install jekyll` in the command line

PS: It is the combination of the two answers in this question.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the ruby-dev file , just go ahead and run this command  - `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my macOS(10.14.2), the reason may be:

> Apparently with OSX el Capitan, there is a new security function that prevents you from modifying system files called Rootless.

My solution is using rvm:

1. [install ruby on Mac OS X with RVM](https://usabilityetc.com/articles/ruby-on-mac-os-x-with-rvm/)
2. gem install jekyll

Answer (score 0):

On windows I have this issue

I actually installed the version rubyinstaller-devkit-2.6.3-1-x64 of ruby

I have removed the ruby completely and Installed the rubyinstaller-devkit-2.5.5-1-x64

and issued the following commands on powershell

```
gem install bundler
gem install jekyll
```

and this time no errors where found

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and of all things, the error was occurring because I hadn't agreed to some updated terms of service in xcode. Running the following did the trick for me. Go figure.

```
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to upgrade homebrew and install `rbenv` to the latest ruby version. After that, I followed the instruction at [jekyll website](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/macos/). My OS is Catalina 2019, I couldn't install Xcode, which is not compatible yet!

> You have to set the path in your `.bash_profile` to make sure that it initializes the `rbenv` when you restart your terminal.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

then

```
$ rbenv version
2.2.3 (set by /Users/mislav/.rbenv/version)
$ rbenv shell
rbenv: no shell-specific version configured
```

hope that help!

Answer (score 0):

## Here is the (only?) reliable and simple way to install Jekyll on macOS

1. Install UTM
2. Install Ubuntu Server
3. Install Jekyll using Ubuntu instructions at https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/ubuntu/
4. Forward port 22 in the VM settings (22->localhost->22)
5. Use VS Code on the macOS host
6. Install Remote SSH
7. Connect to USER@localhost
8. Drag and drop the folder on Mac into VS Code (this transfers files to remote)
9. Enable port forwarding for 4000 (bottom bar on VS Code)
10. Work on your website
11. Right click on your website on the file explorer and click download

If you have not done these steps, you might be delighted by:

1. Ubuntu imports your public SSH key from GitHub
2. VS Code magically handles file transfer in and out
3. VS Code magically installs your VS Code extensions onto the remote server and allows file search on the remote host