# ERROR: Error installing jekyll: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, jekyll-extensions

My system has:

- ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24) [x64-mingw32]
- gem -version 2.2.2
- devKit : DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe

When I try to run `gem install jekyll`, I get this error:

```
D:\devKit>gem install jekyll
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    "D:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe" extconf.rb
D:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe: invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -F (
RuntimeError)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in D:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/g
ems/2.0.0/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensi
ons/x64-mingw32/2.0.0/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 7):

I got this error while installing Jekyll on Linux (Mint 17, which is based on Ubuntu 14.04).

I eventually found the solution [here](http://michaelchelen.net/81fa/install-jekyll-2-ubuntu-14-04/). I needed both the ruby-dev package and nodejs [(the latter due to a bug in Jekyll)](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2327).

```
sudo apt-get install ruby ruby-dev make
sudo gem install jekyll --no-rdoc --no-ri
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem too. Running the following installed Jekyll for me:

> $ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enabled
>
> $ sudo gem install jekyll

This installs RVM, updates Rails and installs Jekyll.

BTW - Most of the posts I've found indicate it's a problem with Xcode not having the developer tools installed. I have a newer MacBook Pro on which this stuff was installed by default, so attempting to install the Xcode dev tools did nothing for me (unlike the above, which did everything I needed).

Comment: Sorry, this is a problem specific to a Mac. Not sure what the scenario is on Windows. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

try

> gem update

then

> gem install jekyll

And you may want to try with Ruby 1.9.3 and compatible DevKit.

Comment: This worked for me on OSX 10.9.5, but I did have to add `sudo` to the front of both commands.