# Error installing Ruby gem Jekyll

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll

Can't install Jekyll on Mac.

I use:

```
sudo gem install jekyll
```

But I have an error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.



Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.1/ext/yajl/gem_make.out
```

Whats wrong? How to fix it?

```
gem -v
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
2.0.14
```

Comment: Try doing `cd  /` then cd to particular directory to try `gem -v`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23298607/3548378 this helped. Seems that jekyll doesn't install without xcode