# installing "make" on Mac

Tags: macos, makefile, memcached, installation

I'm trying to install Memcached on Mac using this tutorial:
http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.de/2011/11/installing-memcached-on-mac-os-x-and.html
but when I try ./configure
it says:
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
when I try make it says:
make
sh: make: command not found
sh-3.2# yum install make
sh: yum: command not found
sh-3.2# apt-get install make
sh: apt-get: command not found

I must mention that I have Xcode but it's still not working.
I'm really new on Mac so please take that into consideration :)
I would really appreciate your help
Thanks!

Comment: Xcode should give you `make` and related tools. What does `printenv PATH | tr ":" "\n"` return?

Comment: It gives:
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/X11/bin
/usr/local/git/bin

Comment: Recent versions of Xcode install their tools in the bundle itself, e.g. `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`.  Try putting that in your `$PATH`.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469994/using-make-on-osx

Answer (score 85, accepted):

If you have Xcode 4.3 or newer the command line tools, such as make, are not installed by default. In Xcode preferences go to the "Downloads" tab and under "Components" push the "Install" button next to "Command Line Tools". After you have successfully downloaded and installed the command line tools you should also type the following command in the Terminal to make sure all your Xcode command line tools are switched to use the 4.3 versions:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Once everything is successfully installed you should see `make` and other command line developer tools in /usr/bin.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot torrey!

Comment: why its not working for me?
still its saying: -bash: make: command not found

Comment: @SazzadTusharKhan - try this: http://daigo.org/2012/10/sh-make-command-not-found-and-other-mountain-lion-issues/ - tl;dr: Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > click "install" next to Command Line Tools.  I have Xcode 4.5.3 currently installed and needed to do this after i updated from Lion to Mountain Lion.

Comment: @torrey.lyons: My current `make` version on my mac is 3.81. How do I upgrade to 4.1? thx

Comment: @LionLai The latest make version distributed by Apple is 3.81, probably due to licensing issues. You'll have to install GNU Make for yourself to get 4.1. See this question for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175529/updating-make-version-4-1-on-mac.

Answer (score 3):

From *torrey.lyons*'s answer, in **Xcode --> Preferences --> Downloads** it says under **Command Line Tools**:

> Before installing, **note that from within Terminal you can use the
>   XCRUN tool to launch compilers and other tools embedded within the
>   Xcode application.** Use the XCODE-SELECT tool to define which version
>   of Xcode is active.  Type "man xcrun" from within Terminal to find out
>   more.

Therefore, I was able to run the make tool with the command `xcrun make`.

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed in Mac OS 11 (Big Sur). There is now a command line tools package. Search for "Command Line Tools for Xcode 12.5.1" (or newer) on Apple's Developer Network.