# Upgrading to Mountain Lion and XCode 4 broke my "make"?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, makefile, osx-mountain-lion, bin

TL/DR: I upgraded stuff and now I can't run "make" - wtf?

I just upgraded from Mac OS X 10.6 to 10.8 Mountain Lion, and then installed XCode 4 (formerly I had Developer/Applications/Xcode (3.something). XCode 4 installed through the App Store application to /Applications.  Somewhere along the way, I can no longer run the "make" command.  And I've tried looking in all the usual /bins but can't find a "make".

Anyone know how to get my "make" command back?

Upgrading Apple stuff always breaks something... (it also broke my "git" command but I got that one back)

Comment: It is lovely ... even upgrading from Lion to Mountain Lion with the XCode broke command line tools. *Seriously?*

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to install the command line tools as described at [installing "make" on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494522/installing-make-on-mac/11494872#11494872). They are not installed by default in Xcode 4.

Comment: OK, so just reinstall it?  I installed the dev tools from XCode 3.whatever a long time ago, seems like make should still be somewhere.

Comment: Just reinstall the command line tools from Xcode 4. In Xcode 4 Preferences go to the "Downloads" tab and under "Components" push the "Install" button next to "Command Line Tools". After you have successfully downloaded and installed the command line tools you should also type the following command in the Terminal to make sure all your Xcode command line tools are switched to use the 4.3 versions: sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Comment: As torrey.lyons stated, I had to run xcode-select after upgrading to mountain lion and xcode 4.4. "sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"

Answer (score 20):

Easiest way to install:

1. Launch XCode
2. Go to Preferences > Downloads > Components
3. Click "Install" next to 'Command Line Tools'