# Updating Make Version on Mac

Tags: macos, makefile

I'm trying to update the version of make on my mac but am running into issues. The minimum project dependency is 4.1 but my version seems to be 3.81. I've updated Xcode to the latest version and installed the command line tools but it still seems to be the older version.

Has anyone run into this issue or know of a way to resolve it?

Comment: Either compile the latest version yourself, or use something like [macports](https://www.macports.org/) or [homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Comment: It's unlikely Apple will ever ship a newer version of GNU make with their system, because the license was changed to GPLv3 and Apple refuses to have anything to do with that license.  I've seen problem reports due to bad patches they've applied to their version anyway.  I agree with user657267, get a copy from homebrew or macports.

Answer (score 45):

Here is what I did, and it works on my MacOS:

Step1: Install homebrew (installation command comes from https://brew.sh/):

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Step2: Use homebrew to install make

```
brew install make --with-default-names
```

just incase it doesn't work, try this:

```
brew install homebrew/dupes/make --with-default-names
```

Step3: You need to change the default command to use correct make instead of the default one from your MacBook or Mac.

For example, if you type

```
make --version
```

You will see:

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

Which is the default path for default version.

So, now, in your .bash_profile (which should be under your home dir /Users/your_name), add the following line:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

> Note: If you see the following message when you installed make:
>
> GNU "make" has been installed as "gmake". If you need to use it as "make", you can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from
>   your bashrc like:
>
> ```
> PATH="/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
> ```
>
> then instead run,
>
> ```
> export PATH="/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
> ```

Then source your .bash_profile. Now try to check your version:

```
make --version
```

It should show:

```
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later     <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Cheers.

Comment: I don't think you should put `/usr/local/Cellar/anything` in your `PATH`, rather, you should put `/usr/local/bin`. If you look in there you will see a symlink to the current version in the Cellar. That way, when you later upgrade to `make v4.3` your PATH will still be correct as **homebrew** will re-symlink the new version. Also your PATH will be correct for *all* **homebrew** packages at a single stroke.

Comment: @Mark Setchell, yes, that's even better solution. I guess my original thought is that it's up to user to define whether he/she want to do this individually or just do it for all the command. Anyway, updated my PATH variable.

Comment: Note: `--with-default-names` was removed from brew. See [Why was –with-default-names removed?](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/why-was-with-default-names-removed/4405/).

Comment: I need to add `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"` line to `~/.profile` on Catalina to persist across boot.

Comment: Same here, I had to add `/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnubin` to the `PATH`. Adding `/usr/local/bin` did not work.

Comment: If `/usr/local/opt/make/libeexec/gnubin/` directory does not exist, you have to use `/opt/homebrew/opt/make/libexec/gnubin` now

Comment: I already had `/usr/local/bin` added to my `PATH`, and on closer inspection I did not have a `make` symlink in my `/usr/local/bin`, but homebrew had made a symlink to `gmake` there instead.  I personally made a symlink in the `/usr/local/bin` for make pointing to the "gmake" Cellar folder that homebrew made.  I had "make" before, but not sure where the command was coming from, and I am not sure and hope that when homebrew make updates the additional symlink will be updated as well.

Comment: I had to add the PATH extension to `/Users/your_name/.zshrc`

Answer (score 18):

Firstly, the current version:

```
$ make --version                  
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

Steps to install/configure:

```sh
brew install make
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

Result:

```
$ make -v
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Note: This is basically a simplified version of @Patrick's answer.

Comment: doesn't work for me, make -v still returns 3.81

Comment: @AntonBelousov the reason it doesn't work is because the `export PATH` specified in this answer is incorrect. You have to run `brew info make` to see the path it suggests. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537173/12042788 answer, as it has correct `export`

Answer (score 6):

If you choose the homebrew method, you should use `brew info make` after `brew install make` succeeds. Then you will see a text like this:

> If you need to use it as "make", you can add a "gnubin" directory
> to your PATH from your bashrc like:
> PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/make/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"

So, add this path in your `.bash_profile`,The detailed steps as:

1. `open ~/.bash_profile`
2. Add line: `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/make/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"`(the path you just got)
3. <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd>
4. `source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 1):

None of the folders from the answers above worked for me, but running `brew info make` outputted the correct one, then I just added to the path.

Folder that worked for me (OS Ventura 13.2.1): `PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/make/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I attempted a fix by a different approach, namely downloading the newer version of GNU Make I want to upgrade into compile that from source downloaded from the official GNU link, instead of using **homebrew**. Then, on my mac, I added a path to my bash shell:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin
```

to the ".bashrc" file in my $HOME directory.

Then reset my Terminal. And, it worked. There seems to be some issue with the **homebrew** download because the formula automatically links the "gmake" installation to the wrong bin, or more accurately missing the bin in the `/usr/local/Cellar/etc./path`. So I reckon that's probably why it does not work as of now. Hope maybe someone will fix that soon.