# upgrade make on MacOS Catalina

Tags: macos, makefile, homebrew, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade make (current version 3.81) on Mac Catalina version 10.15.4.

I found this post that uses brew to do it: [Updating Make Version 4.1 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175529/updating-make-version-4-1-on-mac)

```
brew install make --with-default-names
```

however, the option `--with-default-names` is not supported any more in the brew.

Is there a good example of how to do it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

OK, this seems it worked for me:

```
brew install homebrew/core/make
```

then for using make instead of gmake added to .bash_profile:

```
PATH="/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnubin:${PATH}"
```