# Minimal time difference between prerequisites and target in makefile rule

Tags: makefile

I have a simple makefile:

```
target: prerequisite
    @echo "Touch target"
    @touch target

prerequisite:
    @echo "Touch prerequisite"
    @touch prerequisite
```

The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Example) of GNU make states that the first rule will be executed if `prerequisite` is more recent that `target`. However, if I run the following test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf target prerequisite

make
sleep 0
touch prerequisite
if [[ prerequisite -nt target ]]; then echo "Prerequisit is newer than target"; fi
make

rm -rf target prerequisite
```

it will not execute the first rule twice, the output is:

```
Touch prerequisite
Touch target 
Prerequisit is newer than target
make: `target' is up to date.
```

If I increase the sleep time to e.g. 1, it will execute it though. I'm rather surprised by that behaviour, is there a minimum time difference needed for `make` to consider a file more recent? Apparently the filesystem is aware that the prerequisite is newer.

I run it on MacOS X 11.4 with GNU Make 3.81 built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0.

Comment: I guess the time resolution of this extremely old version of GNU make is not the same as with more recent versions.

Comment: Ah, from a comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175529/updating-make-version-on-mac: "It's unlikely Apple will ever ship a newer version of GNU make with their system, because the license was changed to GPLv3 and Apple refuses to have anything to do with that license."

Comment: Yes, that's why I am using the macports' version. Same for most tools and utilities.

Comment: This is the same reason all the other GNU utilities, including bash (!), on MacOS are stuck at some decrepit old version circa 2007 or so.  This is also why Apple are pushing zsh as the default shell now, even though it's not POSIX-conforming, because they won't update to modern versions.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet This indeed fixes the issue, thx :)