# How to avoid the make command triggers Xcode

Tags: python, xcode, makefile

I have a python project that has a `makefile` which has

```
test: clean lint
    @pytest app/tests/ --cov ./app -s
```

I usually type `make test` in the terminal to trigger this `pytest`. However, recently it stopped working. Instead, I get an error

```
make: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk '' -find make 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 256: (null) (errno=No such file or directory)
```

And MacOS pops up a message window saying it needs to download software (without details other than a progress bar). It takes ~10 min to finish installing. But it doesn't change anything. I have installed XCode although I never used it. `Pytest` still works if I directly type the pytest commands.

My machine is a Macbook Pro with BigSur Intel CPU. I'm not a iOS/MacOS app developer and I don't use Xcode. I don't understand why would `make` triggers it. How to avoid it?

---

More info following @MadScientist suggestion:

```
> type -a make
make is /usr/bin/make

> make --version
OR
> make -d test
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer), missing xcrun at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcrun 

> /usr/bin/make
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer), missing xcrun at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Comment: I do not think this error is being printed by that rule.  The first thing you should always do when debugging a makefile is remove the `@` on your rules as they do nothing but hide critical information.  I recommend you then leave them removed forever (except maybe trivial commands like `echo` etc.)  My suspicion is that either the `make` command you are running is not the normal `make`, or maybe that your makefile is invoking a `$(shell ...)` function or something.

Comment: If you use `type -a make` what do you see?  Is that path a shell script, or the actual make executables?  If you run `make --version` what does it show?  If none of these are helpful you might have to run `make -d test` to try to figure out what command is being run.  That error message doesn't look like anything I've ever seen GNU make print out before.

Comment: @MadScientist You are right that this error has nothing to do with that pytest rule. I tried other rules, or even just an empty makefile, I still get the same error. My guess is somehow XCode gets higher priority for the command `make`. But I'm not familiar enough with either of them to fix it

Comment: @MadScientist I missed your second comment earlier. I added the result to the question.

Comment: Thanks to @MadScientist pointed me to the right direction. It seems like my `/usr/bin/make` was corrupted by the Xcode. I followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175529/updating-make-version-on-mac and ran `brew install make`. It now works