# Failing to install "ez" package in R Studio

Tags: r, package, installation

I'm currently unable to install the `ez` package in `R studio 1.1.456` on macbook. Here is what I am getting:

```r
/bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
make: *** [init.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'zip'
* removing '/anaconda3/lib/R/library/zip'
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package 'zip' had non-zero exit status


ERROR: compilation failed for package 'SparseM'
* removing '/anaconda3/lib/R/library/SparseM'
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package 'SparseM' had non-zero exit status

Warning in install.packages :
installation of package 'ez' had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Go ahead and try `install.packages(zip)` and `install.packages(SparseM)`. It may be that you need dependencies for these dependencies of `ez`. Once you figure out what sub dependencies are required, go ahead and install those, then try to run `install.packages('ez', dependencies = T)` again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!I tried to install individually each required package but failed as well. I run into the same errors (non-zero exit status)

Comment: `/bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
make: *** [init.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'zip'
* removing '/anaconda3/lib/R/library/zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'zip' had non-zero exit status`

Comment: I suspect that you have not yet understood that some packages from some portions of some repositories require system tools for compilation. The error message says you do not have `make`. You should give a more complete description of your setup than just "Rstudio version xxxx-xxx-xxx". The usual method is to include the complete output of `sessionInfo()`. And _as_ _always_ you should include the code that was used.

Comment: User @42- is right on- the problem is in installing the `zip` package, and the source of the problem is you are missing a system tool called `make`. Looks like there is information in the link below that will set you up with the developer tools you need.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469994/using-make-on-osx